# UITableView rows are repeating swift when reodered

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am having a tableview and some data are populated in to the tableview. Now I have a edit option and by clicking on that the user can edit the position of the row by dragging it up or down.

For reordering purpose I am using the delegate functions of the tableView.

For example this is the tableView data

A

B

C

D

Now the problem is that when I click on the edit button and drag the top most cell to the bottom and place it as the last cell, and then scroll the tableView up and down(still in the editing mode) the cell at the bottom (up to which the tableView is seen currently) is repeated.

Now after reordering A to the very bottom and then scrolling up and down

B

C

D

D

After searching I found preapreForReuse, but it is not working.

I am using custom cell class to render the table cell.

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {    
init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    #add the details
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var sdata = self.data[sourceIndexPath.row]
        self.data.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        self.data.insert(sdata, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

It seems very common problem but its not working for me

Hope you understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update the question with tableview datasource method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your model to reflect the change? If your model has D in index 3, then that is what you will display there.

When you move A to D you need to update the model too, not just the table.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by model?

Comment: I am updating the model and it is shown when I save after editing.

Comment: The place you get the data from to fill out the table view cell. Many times its an array. You should be able to call `reloadData` on your table and have all the rows appear in the right spot.

Comment: but if I scroll up the value of C is repeated, so that means its not the problem with the model. its something with the rendering of cell

Comment: You need to post your relevant code. `cellForRowAtindexPath` and the code where you modify the model in response to the table row move